# Meaning of accuracy for sklearn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am doing a project where I predict the outcomes of sporting events. For this, I predict the winner and losers for a single event. I then place a bet depending on this. If I consider all events my strategy makes a positive return on 59% of events.

I want to only place bets on events where I expect to win. For this, I used sklearn to categorize events into events where I can expect to make a profit and those that I would make a loss on. Then I will only place bets on events which are categorized as profitable events. My model has an accuracy of 0.60 and is produced and tested with the following code:

```
knn = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors = 6)
knn.fit(df_classifier, data_indicator)
y = data_indicator.values
X = df_classifier.values
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.3, random_state = 21, stratify = y)
knn = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors = 300)
knn.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred = knn.predict(X_test)
knn.score(X_test,y_test)
```

From my understanding, accuracy is the number of events it correctly predicts. Therefore, if the correct and incorrect prediction is equally distributed over each outcome (profitable and non-profitable events) then 20% of the profitable events would be incorrectly categorized and the same would be for losing events.

**Would this mean that if I only place bets on only predicted profitable events would I would have increased my accuracy from 59% to (59+20)%=79% in making a return on my bet?**

Furthermore, if my reasoning is correct is it possible to see the distribution of correct and incorrect in my outcomes of winning and losing events.

Comment: This does not seem to be a programming problem or question, it is better suited for the Stats SE or Data Science.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand your logic, but this doesn't sound right. It is more like a math problem instead of programing problem. But you can see the distribution of correct and incorrect outcome just by adding this two lines:

```
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
print(confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred))
```

See more detail in : https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#confusion-matrix
Hope this help.

Comment: For `y_test` for each outcome where it was estimated that it would return a profit I then considered if the outcome was profitable or not. There were 7287 predicted profitable outcomes of these 6297 actually resulted in a profitable outcome. Therefore I assume that I have increased my profitable bets from 59% to 86% of bets that were placed. That pretty good in my opinion.

Answer (score 2):

What you essentially doing is binary classification, predict win or lose. Lets say winning is the positive class and losing the negative class, you can have four different outcomes from your prediction:

- True positive (TP): your model predicts win and indeed it was a win
- False positive (FP): your model predicts win but it was a lose
- True negative (TN): your model predicts lose and indeed it was a loose
- False negative (FN): your model predicts lose but it was a win

Accuracy is now (TP+TN)/(TP+FP+TN+FN), basically all correct predictions divided by all predictions. Using this information you can look at metrics like [Precision, Recall and F1-Score](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precision_and_recall) for each class (win & lose) and the confusion matrix ([wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confusion_matrix) & [sklearn-doc](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#confusion-matrix)) to have more insight on your models performance. From there you can calculate your chance of being right if you only bet on win or lose.